# android - activity won't open Animation Drawable issue

Tags: android, animation

I'm animating 20 images using Animation Drawable,i set up an **XML layout** in my drawable folder containing the images and animation duration, and a **JAVA class** that contains the commands. I tried a lot to find the errors, i reduce the size of my images but still won't work, until I saw one line on my java class that has an **Red Exclamation mark** on the line code.

> **imageViews.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.anim_intro_wholenum);**

below is my java class,  the **RED EXCLAMATION MARK** on the left is what i'm talking about. I can't find any dialogue to show what's the problem, I try **Alt + Enter** but nothing shows. i'm sure it's indicating the Line #31 of my code.
I try to remove the line # 31 and run my app, and the activity is working, but there is no **setBackgroundResource** so there's nothing to touch and animate. Can anyone help me? i'm having a hard time on this. thank you

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First,
 you should use OnClickListener instead of calling onTouchListener which will call x2 times on animation.start.

Second, here are some useful links you can use:

similaier questions: 
[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651618/is-it-possible-to-have-an-animated-drawable) 
[Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2902222/apply-an-animation-on-a-drawable-in-android)
Android animation docs: 
[Link 3](http://developer.android.com/intl/ko/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html)

Comment: still not working sir, it says expected source of type is drawable