# Apply animation to Drawable set with drawableLeft

Tags: android, android-animation, android-view, textview, android-drawable

I have icon set as `android:drawableLeft` to `TextView`.

I want to apply some appearance changes some methods to that `Drawable`. 
Since I don't have it's id, I am not able to manipulate its appearance.

Just let me know how to get it's id so that I have its object somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Just let me know how to get it's id.

I assume, that by saying that you expect to receive an id of a `View`, and then to perform animations on that `View`. But, as you know, `TextView` is a descendant of a `View`, **not** `ViewGroup`, thus it's not possible for `TextView` to compound multiple `View`s. Instead, `TextView` lays out a `Drawable` instance.

You can get that `Drawable` and [perform animations on that `Drawable`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26866871/1083957) directly.

[`getCompoundDrawables()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getCompoundDrawables()) will return `Drawable[]` array filled with left, top, right, and bottom `Drawable`s.